# jQuery.parseJSON and HTTP Status

Tags: jquery, http, zend-framework2, status

I'm trying to return a http response with a 402 status code and a JSON content, it's ok, but the problem happens when I try to read this response body using the JQuery.parseJSON(json).

```
$response = new \Zend\Http\Response();
$response->setStatusCode(402);
$response->setContent(json_encode([
    "success" => false,
    "message" => "You need to buy more credits"
]));

return $response;
```

Then I try to read the response content:

```
search: function(term, callback){
   $.post("/api/v1/client/search", {term: term}).always(function(data){
      callback(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
   });
},
```

And I got the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o". When I use the 200 status code everything goes ok, but when I change it to 402 I get this problem.

I don't know if it happens because the browser don't deliver the reponse body assuming the status code as the response itself, but this does not change the fact that the server has sent the message.

Is there a way a can read it?
Have I done some mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: use your browser's developer tools to view the raw data that is returned, also, console.log(data) and see what's actually in there.

Comment: I got the same error with JSON.parse(data), the response content is: "{"success":false,"message":"You need to buy more credits"}".

If I execute JSON.parse('{"success":false,"message":"You need to buy more credits"}'); in console it goes ok, the error happens only when i change the status code.

Comment: Unexpected token signify your javascript cannot parse your data in this case (not everytime), because you encode in JSON your data and you parse again after that. callback(data) should be work with status 402

Comment: Thank you guys, i've found that jquery give different responses for non 200 response status codes and I have posted the solution, you can check it below. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've soved the problem. I hava detected that the object returned by jQuery changes when I change my status header in PHP. When the status code is 200, jQuery returns a string, when status code is 402, jQuery returns a object, and the text I was looking for is the "responseText" property of this object.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ziqtl.png

My solution was:

```
   search: function(term, callback){
        $.post("/api/v1/client/search", {term: term}, function(data){
            callback(JSON.parse(data));
        })
        .fail(function(data){
            callback(JSON.parse(data.responseText));
        });
    },
```